# Spring Data: can I create a method in the @Repository with a name what return list of object if String equals to constant?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Guess easier if I show you my example:

```
@Entity
class User {
    Long id;
    Status status;
}

enum Status {
   NEW("N"), DELETED("D")
}
```

I have an AttributeConverter on `Status` so in DB the enum is stored with one character.

In my database I have entities like:

```
Table user
------------
Id    Status
1       N
2       N
3       D
4       N
5       D
```

I want a method that list the Users with `Status` `D`. Something like this:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    List<User> findByStatusEqualsD();
    or
    List<User> findByStatusEqualsDeleted();
    problem is these are not working
}
```

I could write this:

```
List<User> findByStatus(Status status);
```

And call it as `repo.findByStatus(Status.DELETED)` but I want a method what returns *only* the deleted users.

If I call it as `repo.findByStatus(Status.NEW)` then it will return the *new* users.

I prefer to not write a `@Query`, I hope it is possible what I'm asking without doing it...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think spring jpa named queries don't have any out of box solution available for your requirement. Only straightforward way I am thinking is to use `@Query` with hard-coded where clause (i.e. where status="D").

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JpaRepository with Enum: findAllByOfferState\_ACTIVE. NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46389568/jparepository-with-enum-findallbyofferstate-active-nosuchelementexception)

Comment: thanks @HopeyOne , that is one of good option.

Answer (score 0):

Such behavior is not supported.

Method name is translated into JPQL expression (which is the same as used in `@Query`) with parameters in it (if needed) so you have to provide these. (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation)

If you want query parameters to be *hardcoded* - `@Query` is what you need.

Alternatively you can have default method in your repository calling the parametrized one as mentioned here [JpaRepository with Enum: findAllByOfferState_ACTIVE. NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46389568/jparepository-with-enum-findallbyofferstate-active-nosuchelementexception)

Answer (score 0):

Easy,

You don't need a repo for that. Create a **Service** instead:

```
public interface UserDAOService{
    List<User> getAllDeletedUsers();
}
```

And then just implement it with hardcoded findByStatus method from repo:

```
@Service
public class UserDAOServiceImpl implements UserDAOService{

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public UserDAOServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository= userRepository;
    }

    
    @Override
    public List<Author> getAllDeletedUsers();
        return userRepository.findByStatus(Status.DELETED);
    }
```